# Gradle Task Groups not visible in Gluon Project

Tags: gradle, gluon, buildship

When I create a new Gluon Project with the Eclipse Gluon Plugin(2.3.0), the Gradle Tasks View (Buildship) only shows the group 'other', where all tasks get listed. 
Calling `gradle tasks` on the command line, shows all groups as expected, as well as when I create a new Gradle Project without the plugin. 
Furthermore the Executions View doesn't show anything

(Gradle STS Integration for Eclipse is also installed)

Comment: Recently we changed the Eclipse plugin, so it doesn't use STS anymore. I'll file an issue and see if we can get the groups of tasks under the Tasks View.

Comment: @JoséPereda Yes. I've been working through the tutorial http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/4.0.1/#eclipse-plugin and am really confused that it doesn't match the current plugin. Do I need to install Buildship and how do I run/compile for mobile because I don't see any tasks for that there?

Comment: Indeed, there are a few screenshots that are outdated (as those are still referred to STS). Eclipse Mars already includes Buildship, so you just need to click on Eclipse->Window->Show View->Other... and select Gradle->Gradle Tasks (note, the one with the light green 'G' icon).

Comment: @JoséPereda sorry didn't see your response because of no @ sign. Thanks for the reply. That's what I did and I don't see any task for mobile. [Here is a screenshot of the tasks](http://imgur.com/a/9fFBN). I followed the tutorial and the screenshot is for the tutorial's given project that the plugin creates..

Comment: @Mark it is hard to say, and even harder to solve it within these comments. Please post a new question, so you can provide more details

Comment: @JoséPereda Here is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40337578/cant-build-a-gluon-project-for-mobile-using-gradle