# How to generate an apk from Gluon Javafx app

Tags: android, javafx, apk, gluon

I'am new, so pardon my silly question... But i would like to know how or where do i go do generate an apk in gluon for eclipse 2.40, in the previous versions it was tha "android" gridle task... But it does not exist anymore. 
Thanks

Comment: Probably you need to check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40358734/3956070)?

Comment: I cant thank you enough Mr. @JoséPereda... Always here for me... May God bless you and your family! Sorry that i cant see "Mark as answer" here... But my question is answered! But without wantng to bother or abuse... Could give me tips or point me where to learn how work with diferent screen sizes? I am having so many problems with this... In desktop i know that its all about layouts... I would like to understand it in mobile.

Comment: Have you tried the different Gluon [samples](http://gluonhq.com/support/samples/)? Please, create a new question and explain what you have already tried.

Comment: Thank you Sir!!! I getting a lot information with the samples... i am currently recreating them. @JoséPereda

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't build a gluon project for mobile using gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40337578/cant-build-a-gluon-project-for-mobile-using-gradle). This was my question and you fell into the same pit that I did - old documentation. You can mark your question as a duplicated and it will close it.