# Gluon Java FX Gradle Task: androidInstall is not there

Tags: javafx, gluon-mobile

After installing Gluon on (Eclipse Neon 4.6.2) I can see the Gradle Task 'run' but the task 'androidInstall' (for installing to the device) is not visible. if I click to the task installApp happens also nothing

I tried to do the steps at:
http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/#_prerequisites

but the Android SDK with the Android Support Library is not available anymore. 
is that the reason? any ideas?

Comment: For viewing the tasks on Eclipse, check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40337578/cant-build-a-gluon-project-for-mobile-using-gradle/40358734#40358734). For the Android Support Library replacement check this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133317/javafxports-android-gradle-task-requires-android-support-library-which-is-re), you can use fxmobile plugin 1.3.1